# swift: how to generate arm7 or arm64 from the command line

Tags: swift, command-line

Using the Xcode 8.3 beta incarnation of `swiftc`, how do you generate an Arm7 or Arm64 binary?

I've tried the obvious argument `-target-cpu arm64` which gives me a linker message `<unknown>:0: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mcpu=arm64'
ld: library not found for -lobjc` and it plows ahead trying to build an x64 target.

Actual command:

```
swiftc -sdk /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/ -L /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/lib -F /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/ -swift-version 3 -target-cpu arm64 somefile.swift
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can use the sdk and target option to do this. Here is an example:

```
/Projects/Test $ cat main.swift 
print("Hello world!");
```

### Compiling for x86_64

```
/Projects/Test $ swiftc main.swift 
/Projects/Test $ lipo -info main
Non-fat file: main is architecture: x86_64
/Projects/Test $ ./main
Hello world!
```

### Compiling for armv7

```
/Projects/Test $ swiftc main.swift -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.2.sdk -target armv7-apple-ios8.1
/Projects/Test $ lipo -info main
Non-fat file: main is architecture: armv7
```

### Compiling for arm64

```
/Projects/Test $ swiftc main.swift -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.2.sdk -target arm64-apple-ios8.1
/Projects/Test $ lipo -info main
Non-fat file: main is architecture: arm64
```

I wrote a script `build.sh` so that its easier to use:

```
#!/bin/sh
TARGET_MAC_VERSION=10.11
TARGET_IOS_VERSION=8.1

if [ "$#" -ne 2 ]; then
    echo "Usage $0: <armv7/arm64/x86_64> <file>"
    exit
fi

if [ "$1" != 'armv7' ] && [ "$1" != 'arm64' ] && [ "$1" != 'x86_64' ]; then
  echo "Usage $0: <armv7/arm64/x86_64>"
  exit
fi

if [ "$1" == 'x86_64' ]; then
  SDK=macosx
  TARGET="x86_64-macosx$TARGET_MAC_VERSION"
else
  SDK=iphoneos
  TARGET="$1-apple-ios$TARGET_IOS_VERSION"
fi
echo "xcrun -sdk  $SDK swiftc $2 -target $TARGET"
xcrun -sdk  $SDK swiftc $2 -target $TARGET
```

Output

```
  $ ./build.sh armv7 main.swift 
xcrun -sdk  iphoneos swiftc main.swift -target armv7-apple-ios8.1
  $ lipo -info main
Non-fat file: main is architecture: armv7
  $ ./build.sh arm64 main.swift 
xcrun -sdk  iphoneos swiftc main.swift -target arm64-apple-ios8.1
  $ lipo -info main
Non-fat file: main is architecture: arm64
  $ ./build.sh x86_64 main.swift 
xcrun -sdk  macosx swiftc main.swift -target x86_64-macosx10.11
  $ lipo -info main
Non-fat file: main is architecture: x86_64
```

Edit Note: Optimized the script based on the input from @jens. See the comments for more information.

Comment: Just a recommendation for optimisation: Instead of retrieving the path to the sdk from `xcrun` you can just use `xcrun` directly, e.g., `xcrun -sdk iphoneos10.3 swiftc -target armv7-apple-ios10.3 main.swift`. That simplifies your script a bit.

Comment: true. I think instead of `iphoneos10.3`, we can just use `xcrun -sdk iphoneos swiftc -target armv7-apple-ios10.3 main.swift`. I was trying to make it more independent of version installed on mac.